# Dynamic Buttons According to URL parameter

Tags: urls, conditional-content

I am working on a WordPress Site. I just want to add a button on a page and track its behavior.

My main question is when I create a campaign URL, I just want to change button behavior according to the URL parameter.

For example:

Imagine, I have a URL such as http://mylocalsite.com/campaign-page/?campaign=linkedin
. I just want to show a button that goes to the LinkedIn url.

On the other hand, imagine, I have a http://mylocalsite.com/campaign-page/?campaign=facebook
and then I want to show the same or different button that goes to Facebook URL.

Is there any way to do that? I can create campaign URLs with some marketing plugins, but I could not find a plugin that makes button smart according to URL.

Thanks in advance for suggestions

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress, simple `if else` statement in PHP will do it.. `if ($_GET['campaign'] == 'linkedin') { echo '<a href="#">LinkedIn</a>'; } elseif ($_GET['campaign'] == 'facebook') { echo '<a href="#">Facebook</a>'; }`

Comment: It works with code snippet tools. But there is a problem with giving URL as snippet to button. I can handle it different way, I think. Thanks a lot